# Github repository not cloning using gh cli

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, git-clone, github-cli

I want to clone my public repository from Github to my local system using `gh` official cli.

I copied the following command from the repo (green code button) button and also followed the official documentation -

```
sudo gh repo clone <username>/<repo-name>
```

But the repository does not clone, but instead, the command returns the following output on the terminal.

```
Welcome to GitHub CLI!

To authenticate, please run `gh auth login`.
```

I also executed `gh auth login` and logged in. But still, the command returns the same output.

I can clone the same repository using following command

```
git clone "url"
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. How can I clone the repository using `gh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will face this problem if you install gh using snap. More about this issue [here](https://github.com/cli/cli/discussions/3300).

### Solution

Install gh using official sources - https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#official-sources

Answer (score 1):

Try the command without sudo : gh repo clone (username)/(repo-name). If login is successfully done, this should work. For reference you can check[1].

[1][make git clone with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917237/make-git-clone-with-sudo)

Comment: without sudo it gives following error - fatal: could not create work tree dir 'devashishprasad': Permission denied
exit status 128

Comment: And I can clone it using git clone, no issues with that one.

Answer (score -1):

if then ">" probably if then "~>"

trying to work out Ganache principles for symbolic logic using UC Berkeley style.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).