# How to git stash in linux if i don't have permision to change one of child files

Tags: linux, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo

I have to stash files which are in my LINUX WSL folder.
But when i try to run `git stash` i recieve this error:

```
error: open("cloudformation/deployStacks.sh"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path cloudformation/deployStacks.sh
Cannot save the current worktree state
```

I tried to run `chmod u=rwx,g=r,o=r cloudformation` ,

```
chmod u=rwx,g=r,o=r cloudformation/deployStacks.sh

chmod 777 cloudformation
```

But none of this worked.
Maybe anyone knows how to solve this permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some time of struglling  i found way to do it
`sudo git stash` worked just great!

Comment: Well, if you have sudo privileges you can use it to change file permission in the first place. Using git with sudo is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Asocia Why it's horrible idea ?

Comment: Because you will write/modify some files as root and you won't be able to use git without sudo again.

Comment: This is **very** bad, as you're giving git sudo permissions, which means it could modify ANY files on your disk. You were on the right lines with `chmod`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917354/979052)